# How would I create a circular brick platform?

Tags: modeling, texturing, workflow

i'm new to blender, and wanted to make some assets for ue4. I want to make a platform like this [image: example].  I've tried a lot of different things, and only one has worked somewhat so far.  Here's my result [image: myexample].  I can't seem to get the same result as he did.  How would you suggest to get similar results, look wise and detail wise.(Each of his bricks looks different and unique, i.e scratches and size, where with my result I just made a circle extruded it and added faces) Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array modifiers.
1st create a nice brick.
[image: brick]
Then add an array modifier with a relative offset of 1 on X axis. Change the count to see the effect (I used 5), but it won't be used later.
[image: array 1]
Add another array modifier with a relative offset of 1 in Y axis. The count will be used and can be adjusted as you like.
[image: array 2]
Add a curve circle. It has to be a curve, not a mesh.
[image: circle]
Select your brick and add a curve modifier, set the "object" as your curve circle.
[image: curve modifier]
You can see the shape changing to semi-circular.
Now in the 1st array modifier, change the fit type to "fit curve"
[image: fit curve]
This will adjust the number of bricks to fit the curve's length. Scale smoothly your brick to adjust.
[image: result]